# quarkus 2.1.4 - mvnw quarkus:dev not working on windows 10

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm trying to run the project hibernate-orm-quickstart from  https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/hibernate-orm-quickstart

but when I execute "mvnw compile quarkus:dev" it is showing an error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.1.4.Final:dev (default-cli) on project hibernate-orm-quickstart: Execution default-cli of goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven
-plugin:2.1.4.Final:dev failed: A required class was missing while executing io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.1.4.Final:dev: org/fusesource/jansi/internal/Kernel32
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.1.4.Final
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-maven-plugin/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-maven-plugin-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-core/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-core-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-app-model/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-app-model-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.2.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/commons-logging-jboss-logging/1.0.0.Final/commons-logging-jboss-logging-1.0.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-maven-resolver/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-maven-resolver-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logmanager/jboss-logmanager-embedded/1.0.9/jboss-logmanager-embedded-1.0.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-embedder/3.8.1/maven-embedder-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.4/commons-cli-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-connector-basic/1.6.2/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-transport-wagon/1.6.2/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http/3.4.3/wagon-http-3.4.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/3.4.3/wagon-http-shared-3.4.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.12.1/jsoup-1.12.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.15/commons-codec-1.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.14/httpcore-4.4.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-file/3.4.3/wagon-file-3.4.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-gradle-resolver/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-gradle-resolver-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-io/1.6.0/smallrye-common-io-1.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-core-deployment/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-core-deployment-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/aesh/readline/2.1/readline-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/common/wildfly-common/1.5.4.Final-format-001/wildfly-common-1.5.4.Final-format-001.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/gizmo/gizmo/1.0.9.Final/gizmo-1.0.9.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/9.1/asm-util-9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/9.1/asm-tree-9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/9.1/asm-analysis-9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.3.0.Final/jandex-2.3.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.1/asm-9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-development-mode-spi/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-development-mode-spi-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-class-change-agent/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-class-change-agent-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-utilities/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-devtools-utilities-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.4/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-core/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-core-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/config/smallrye-config/2.4.4/smallrye-config-2.4.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/config/smallrye-config-core/2.4.4/smallrye-config-core-2.4.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/microprofile-config-api/2.0/microprofile-config-api-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-annotation/1.6.0/smallrye-common-annotation-1.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-expression/1.6.0/smallrye-common-expression-1.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-function/1.6.0/smallrye-common-function-1.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-constraint/1.6.0/smallrye-common-constraint-1.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-classloader/1.6.0/smallrye-common-classloader-1.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/config/smallrye-config-common/2.4.4/smallrye-config-common-2.4.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/2.2.1.Final/jboss-logging-annotations-2.2.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/jboss/threads/jboss-threads/3.4.2.Final/jboss-threads-3.4.2.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-bootstrap-runner/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-bootstrap-runner-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-builder/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-builder-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/sdk/graal-sdk/21.1.0/graal-sdk-21.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-launcher/1.7.2/junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.0/apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.7.2/junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.2.0/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.7.2/junit-platform-commons-1.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.7.2/junit-jupiter-5.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.7.2/junit-jupiter-api-5.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-params/5.7.2/junit-jupiter-params-5.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.7.2/junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-project-core-extension-codestarts/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-project-core-extension-codestarts-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-common/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-devtools-common-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-registry-client/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-devtools-registry-client-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[62] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-artifact-api/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-devtools-artifact-api-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[63] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-message-writer/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-devtools-message-writer-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[64] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/common/smallrye-common-os/1.6.0/smallrye-common-os-1.6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[65] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-base-codestarts/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-devtools-base-codestarts-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[66] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-devtools-codestarts/2.1.4.Final/quarkus-devtools-codestarts-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[67] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/qute/qute-core/2.1.4.Final/qute-core-2.1.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[68] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/reactive/mutiny/0.19.2/mutiny-0.19.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[69] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.3/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[70] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[71] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/jline/jline/3.20.0/jline-3.20.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[72] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[73] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/io/fabric8/maven-model-helper/18/maven-model-helper-18.jar
[ERROR] urls[74] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1.3/jdom-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[75] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.12.4/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.12.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[76] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.29/snakeyaml-1.29.jar
[ERROR] urls[77] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.2.1/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[78] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/jakarta/inject/jakarta.inject-api/1.0/jakarta.inject-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[79] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/jakarta/enterprise/jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api/2.0.2/jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api-2.0.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[80] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/jakarta/el/jakarta.el-api/3.0.3/jakarta.el-api-3.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[81] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/jakarta/interceptor/jakarta.interceptor-api/1.2.5/jakarta.interceptor-api-1.2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[82] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.25/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[83] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[84] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[85] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-builder-support/3.8.1/maven-builder-support-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[86] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-util/1.6.2/maven-resolver-util-1.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[87] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.3.3/maven-shared-utils-3.3.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[88] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.2.1/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[89] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[90] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/30.1.1-jre/guava-30.1.1-jre.jar
[ERROR] urls[91] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[92] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-
guava.jar
[ERROR] urls[93] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.2.0/error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[94] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[95] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/2.1.0/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[96] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-artifact-transfer/0.10.0/maven-artifact-transfer-0.10.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[97] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/3.0.1/maven-common-artifact-filters-3.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[98] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[99] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[100] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.31/freemarker-2.3.31.jar
[ERROR] urls[101] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jakarta.json/1.1.6/jakarta.json-1.1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[102] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.12.4/jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[103] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.12.4/jackson-annotations-2.12.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[104] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.12.4/jackson-core-2.12.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[105] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/twdata/maven/mojo-executor/2.3.1/mojo-executor-2.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[106] = file:/C:/Users/henri/.m2/repository/org/jboss/slf4j/slf4j-jboss-logmanager/1.1.0.Final/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I'm using:
windows 10
java 11
quarkus 2.1.4, it didn't happen on 2.0.3-final

when I run it on Linux Ubuntu I get no errors and the project works fine.

Thank you for any help
Henrique

Comment: I think you may be missing a dll  'kernel32.dll', or if its there it could be that the 'org/fusesource/jansi' is looking for it in the wrong place

Answer (score 3):

workaround

adding jline dependency to the pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>jline</groupId>
            <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.6</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

From : https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19673#issuecomment-906685436

looks like it is a known issue on quarkus
Thank you all for helping